# Authorisation Filter continues on when status code set .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On my Controller Method I have:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorisation(),HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
          return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

In my Authorisation filter I have:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
   …..
   context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return;
   …..
```

When it hit's the above code in my authorisation filter. The code still continues to the view. Placing a breakpoint on the view, if I then do the following in the immediate window:

```
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode
```

It returns me 401 as expected.

back in my startup.cs file I have:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/user/signin/");
    }
});
```

I don't understand why the controller continues through to the view under this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to trigger the authorization short circuiting behavior of the filter pipeline, you need to set the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.authorizationfiltercontext.result?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_AuthorizationFilterContext_Result) on the [filter context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.authorizationfiltercontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> Gets or sets the result of the request. Setting Result to a non-`null` value inside an authorization filter will short-circuit the remainder of the filter pipeline.

So your filter should do something like this:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    // …
    context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);
}
```

You can also direclty use a [`UnauthorizedResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.unauthorizedresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead:

```
context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
```

Btw. I would suggest you to take a look at the [security chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) of the ASP.NET Core documentation. The authentication and authorization stack that the framework comes with is really powerful and you can probably utilize it to directly achieve what you are trying to do there. If set up properly, redirecting to a login page for example is something that comes by default.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost working. after returning, it now doesn't continue to my view, however it seems to go nowhere now. I'm guessing that setting the Result doesn't set the context.response.StatusCode so the redirect in the startup doesn't get triggered. I've been told I cant use the full framework, so this is the best alternative I can come up with. So how can I 'react' to this after setting result?

Comment: Since you want to redirect *anyway*, you could also just return a [`RedirectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) directly. So you don’t need to make the indirection over the status code (the redirect will overwrite the status anyway). *“I can’t use the full framework”* – Why not?

Comment: We cant use the full framework because my boss deams it 'to heavy' for our needs. So we create a session cookie on start up and then when the user logs on we store in another cookie the user login and the same session. When the API gets called for now, it's enough to check that both session cookies are set with the same session. I'm sure I'll end up using full claims and principal, but for now I have to appease my boss.

Answer (score 1):

To send Unauthorized status code with response message

```
context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(new { message = "Unauthorized User!" });
```